# Connect to Onedrive associated with Lumia 1020 on Lumia 950

Tags: onedrive

I purchased a Lumia 1020 and contract from EE a couple of years ago. I don't remember setting up Ondrive so I don't know the account name, but it was active on the phone. Recently the Lumia 1020 died so I replaced with a Lumia 950 and have kept the same phone number and plan.
Is there any way I can access the photos and files from the Ondrive account associated with my 1020?
When trying to set up Onedrive on the 950, I've tried using the only 2 email addresses I've ever had, and also my phone number, but no account is recognised.
Any suggestions for course of action?

Answer (score 3):

When you initially set up the Lumia 1020, it would've been set up against a Microsoft account - typically, this would be a hotmail/outlook.com email address, but it could've been against a different email address (such as your work, or even Gmail). This would also have been your primary account which would've been used for app purchases etc.

When setting up your 950, if you gave the same account as the primary account, it would've offered to restore the backup from your 1020, and it would also automatically tie in with your OneDrive accounts.

If you can still boot your old Lumia 1020, you should be able to go to settings > accounts and find the account details there, but if it is fully dead, or you've already reset it to factory defaults, your only recourse is to search through all your old emails to see if you've got the original confirmation of email address email for setting up the Microsoft account.